# How to validate multiple elements with same name but with different types

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm trying to validate an XML against an XSD that has duplicate elements with different types. But Can't get this to work.

**XML**

```
<notifications xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
    <Notification>
        <sObject xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Tracking">
            <sf:Id>a2L1g000000OzM7EAK</sf:Id>
        </sObject>
        <sObject xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Log">
            <sf:Id>a1t1g000001wMQrAAM</sf:Id>
        </sObject>
    </Notification>
</notifications>
```

As you can see in the above `sObject` element is occurring twice. Following is the XSD I have comeupwith.

**Main XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:ob="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import schemaLocation="schema1.xsd" namespace="urn:sobject.soap.sforce.com" />
  <xs:element name="notifications">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Notification">
         <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="sObject" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="ob:Tracking" />
              <!--xs:element name="sObject" type="ob:Log"/-->
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="Tracking">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="sf:Id" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="Log">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="sf:Id" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Dependent schema1.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:sobject.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:string" />
</xs:schema>
```

Note: I can't change the XML structure as it is coming from an external system and this is a minimal reproducible sample and the actual XML is pretty complex.

Comment: You can't have two elements of the same name and different types at the same level. That is just invalid in a XSD.   You might have to look at having something pre-parse the XML and make the names of those element unique, e.g sTrackingObject and sLogObject.

Comment: Dijkgraaf is correct, but it is possible to create an XSD which models this XML. You need to use complex type inheritance. However, before going down that road...have you tried to obtain the official XSD from Salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to define a base type `sObjectType` as the supertype of `Log` and `Tracking`. I defined it as an abstract type because it would make no sense to actually have an element using it.

This seems to work for me:

**Notifications.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    targetNamespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"

    xmlns:not="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound" 
    xmlns:sobj="urn:sobject.soap.sforce.com">

    <xs:import schemaLocation="schema1.xsd" namespace="urn:sobject.soap.sforce.com" />

    <xs:element name="notifications">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Notification">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="sObject" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                                type="not:sObjectAbstractType" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="sObjectAbstractType" abstract="true" />

    <xs:complexType name="Tracking">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="not:sObjectAbstractType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="sobj:Id" />
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Log">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="not:sObjectAbstractType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="sobj:Id" />
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```